# Can't create a new app in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I want to create a new app in iTunes Connect so I can prepare and submit my app. I can click on the '+' sign and the pop-up show and I can select 'New app'.

I enter my info but the create button is disabled.

[image]

I have verified in the 'Agreements, Tax, and Banking' that the contracts (for free apps) are signed. (Contracts for the paid apps are signed but not set up: I can't do that set up, it's a client account).

I have verified in the developer.apple.com portal that the license is agreed to.

I have also verified in my personnal account that I can create a new app (to check if it's an iTunesConnect-wide issue) but it's ok there.

I have also tried different browsers and tried emptying the cache.

My iTunes Connect home page doesn't show any warning or messages.
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: since this is not your primary account. Can you check what type of role is assigned to you? https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Users%20and%20Roles_Overview

Comment: Very good question: I have all the roles assigned to me. I should also mentionned that I successfully create a new app 3 days ago in that same account.

Comment: can you try the same through account owner's id? rest of the process can be done through your account. If account owner also cannot do this then it's agreement issue

Comment: My Apple ID is the only id in this account. If it's an agreement issue, where should I look? (Given I already looked in developer.apple.com and itunesconnect)?

Comment: itunesconnect top row it will show you message if any agreements needs to be renewed or signed

Comment: @AmodGokhale I added a picture in the question. Is the top row you're referring to in the page shown in the picture?

Comment: looks good. better raise a query with apple

Comment: I'm facing the same problem right now

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I did called support. They opened a ticket with the engineering team. @BrenoMacena i suggest you do the same.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you ever find a solution?  I've reached out to apple and am just left waiting for them to get back to me.

Comment: No I did not hear from them. I tried a few days later and it worked. I don't have any solution, alas.